# Why is boost::process::spawn leaving zombies behind?

Tags: zombie-process, boost-process

I am calling an external utility (`advzip`) from a code to run asynchronous recompression on written data. I use `boost::process::spawn` to do that:

```
// std::string f;
auto p=boost::process::search_path("advzip");
if(p.empty()) return;
boost::process::spawn(p,"-q","-z","-2",f);
```

These subprocesses, however, stay around in zombie state - after they've completed their work - which is not supposed to happen as per [`boost::process::spawn` documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost/process/spawn.html.). Am I doing something wrong?

I am using boost 1.65, running under Ubuntu 18.04.

[image: htop screenshot]

Comment: Are you using threads? https://github.com/klemens-morgenstern/boost-process/issues/153